# Google Maps Infobox and jQuery

Tags: jquery, infobox

I am using infobox to display some data related to the marker. The data contains html code and in particular a div with a class `test`.

The weird thing is that I cannot seem to access this html code, as the following code does not work:

```
  $(".test").live("hover", function(){
      alert("hover");
  });
```

I am stressing the fact that the exact code works fine with InfoWindow. I can also confirm that the the complete html shows up, as I can see it using FireBug.

I know that `live()` has been depreciated but I am using and older jQuery version.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Can you add more of your code? It's unclear as to where the problem could be based on what you have in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

I had to set enableEventPropagation: true in the InfoBox options.

Thanks!

Comment: You can accept this answer (even though it<s your own) if it solved your problem. Though I might add some more detail.