# Mousing over Infobox fires hover event on markers that are behind it

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently using the InfoBox plugin for Google Maps. Unfortunately, I've run into an annoying problem.

Users on my app can open an InfoBox by hovering over its corresponding marker. That works fine. The problem occurs when the InfoBox is open and the user is mousing over it. For some reason, the markers **beneath** the InfoBox are firing off their mouseover events. This is a big issue because it closes the current box before opening the box belonging to the marker that has just fired off its mouseover event. I've done some searching and I've found out that setting each marker to:

```
optimized: false
```

prevents this bug. However, this option slows down the map and makes it feel cumbersome to use.

My InfoBox:

```
infoWindows[obj.VehicleName] = new InfoBox({
    content: contentString,
    disableAutoPan: false,
    maxWidth: 500,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-250, -490),
    boxStyle: {
         width: "500px"
    },
    enableEventPropagation: false,
    infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(45, 1)
});
```

My listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
```

Comment: You are not alone [When a marker lies behind open infobox - Event mouseover with InfoBox plugin Google Maps API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691088/when-a-marker-lies-behind-open-infobox-event-mouseover-with-infobox-plugin-goo).  You need to stop the propagation of the event in the InfoBox.

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944058/google-maps-infobox-and-jquery/13944103#13944103 (perhaps setting enableEventPropagation:false?)

Comment: enableEventPropagation:false doesn't seem to work, unfortunately. I tried setting it to false and it didn't seem to do anything. Maybe one of my other settings are interfering.

Comment: The [documentation](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html) says it defaults to false.

Comment: I managed to come up with a dirty fix for it. See the answer section if you're interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ugly fix because none of the advertised options (enableEventPropagation) seemed to be working for me (and I certainly didn't want to go down the route of using "optimized:false" on 300+ markers)

Inside the mouseover listener for each marker, I do a check to see if the currently-opened InfoWindow is being hovered over:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {

    //If an InfoBox is currently open
    if(openInfoBox !== null){

        var id = $(openInfoBox.getContent()).attr('id');
        //If the main div inside that InfoBox is currently being hovered over
        if ($('#' + id + ':hover').length) {
            return false; //go no further. i.e. ignore mouseover event for marker
        }

    }

    //Open InfoBox etc etc
```